# How do I click on an image outside the defined region?

Tags: python, automation, sikuli

Can anyhelp me with the following problem:

I have defined a region with Sikuli. 
But now I would like to click on every button that falls outside my defined region. 
Does anyone know how to do that?

```
ImageX2 = ("imageX2.png")
regionIn = find(ImageX2).below()
regionIn.highlight(5)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `Region` method `contains` for that.

So if you have a defined region:

```
region = Region(x,y,w,h)
```

And you have multiple buttons on the screen:

```
buttonImageName = "image.png"
buttons = findAll(button)
```

Iterate over your findings and only pick the ones that are outside your region

```
for button in buttons:
    if region.contains(button):
        continue # that will skip the buttons inside your region
    else:
        button.click() # that will click on the buttons outside your region
```